# How to add available qty to cart when customer request more than available qty?

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, stock

As asked in the question, Is there any possibility to add available qty(in stock) to the cart when customer requesting more than available qty.

**How magento behave with this situation?**

ex :

I have **5** qty in **product A**, Customer requesting **10**. I want to add the available **5** to the cart and show a message to customer.

Comment: You can apply check using jquery, can you please share your code?

Comment: i did not try in any code level.very beginning i am asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using plugin:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="sr_check_stock" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Quote.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory as DataObjectFactory;

class Quote
{
    /**
     * @var StockRegistryInterface
     */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var DataObjectFactory
     */
    private $objectFactory;

    /**
     * Quote constructor.
     *
     * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
    ) {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $request
    ) {
        if ($request === null) {
            $request = 1;
        }
        if (is_numeric($request)) {
            $request = $this->objectFactory->create(['qty' => $request]);
        }

        if ($product->getId() && $request) {
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            if ($stockItem->getQty() < $request->getQty()) {
                $remainingQty = $request->getQty() - $stockItem->getQty();
                $request->setQty($stockItem->getQty());
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('%1 item not available', $remainingQty));
            }
        }

        return [$product, $request];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, was these files do the work or want to completely add the plugin files

Comment: You need to adjust with your module.

Comment: do i need add any observer here or just with the basic module setup and add these files to relevent location is enough?

Comment: just with the basic module setup and add these files to relevent location is enough?

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: thank you for your answer, its working.Message is not showing.available qty is added to the cart.

Comment: can you please help me regarding the message?

Comment: Message should work, I have tested when I post this answer. Your product adding success message work or not?

Comment: product adding success message working